# Jcombobox options switching between panels with tickboxes Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, calculator, jcombobox

I'm new to Java, I want to do the following:

The user selects an option from the JComboBox which will fire the following:

New panel shows up in the same frame, containing 5 tickboxes. Each tickbox has a value.
The user selects 2 tickboxes, clicks "Calculate" 
New TextBox is fired with the sum of the values.

The user changes the selection from the ComboBox, the previous frame is removed and a new one shows up.

The idea above is a calculator, but a bit more complicated than the conventional one.

Your time and help will be much appreciated. I'm using the gui form in IntelliJ. Here is what I've got so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class CastCalculator {
    private JPanel MainPanel;
    private JLabel CastImage;
    private JComboBox buidlingChoice;
    private JComboBox procurementChoice;
    private JCheckBox pMFoundationsCheckBox;
    private JCheckBox pMFrameElementsCheckBox;

    private JPanel House;
    private JPanel fiveStorey;
    private JPanel traditional;


    private JPanel finalCalculation;

    private JRadioButton radioButton1;
    private JButton calculateButton;
    double pmFoundationsValue;
    private JPanel resultPanel;

    String toString(double d) {
        return null;
    }
    private CastCalculator(){
        calculator();
    }

    private void calculator(){

        House.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hi Michelle");
            }
        });
        pMFoundationsCheckBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (pMFoundationsCheckBox.isSelected())
                    pmFoundationsValue = 1.5;
                }
        });
        String pmFV = Double.toString( pmFoundationsValue );
        calculateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void houseComboBox {
        String[] buildingStrings = {"House", "5-Storey Building", "10-Storey Building"};
        String[] procurementStrings = {"Traditional", "2-D", "3-D"};

        JComboBox<String> buildingList = new JComboBox<>( buildingStrings );
        buildingList.setSelectedIndex( 3 );
        buildingList.addActionListener( (ActionListener) this );
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Object e;
        e) {

        }
    }
    private void createUIComponents() {
        CastImage = new JLabel( (new ImageIcon( "cast.png" )) );
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame( "Cast PMV Calculator" );
        mainFrame.setContentPane( new CastCalculator().calculator);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        mainFrame.pack();
        //mainFrame.setSize(500,600);
        mainFrame.setVisible( true );
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide us with your own work. This includes but is not limited to actual code implementation you have done and the results of your own conducted research. **This is not a coding service**. It is expected of you to try to solve your problems yourself first and if you get stuck somewhere in the process come here to ask for guidance.

Comment: Sure, just a second.